# Source for quotes regarding Perek Shirah

Tags: sources-mekorot, perek-shira

In my [copy of Perek Shirah](https://www.artscroll.com/Details.aspx?itemNo=9781578194230), there are several passages included before and after Perek Shirah, attributed to various Tannaim (translations are Artscroll's, but I corrected some typos):

> אמר רבי, כל העוסק בפרק שירה בעולם הזה, זוכה ללמוד וללמד, לשמור ולעשות ולקים, ותלמודו מתקים בידו, וניצול מיצר הרע, ומפגע רע, ומחבוט הקבר, ומדינה של גיהנם, [ומחבלו של משיח,] ומאריך ימים, וזוכה לימות המשיח ולחיי העולם הבא
>
> Rabbi [Yehudah the Prince] said: Whoever is engrossed in *Perek Shirah* in this World will merit to learn, teach, observe, perform, and fulfill, and his Torah learning will remain with him; he will be rescued from the Evil Inclination, from an evil occurrence, from jostling in the grave, from the judgement of Gehenna, and from the birthpangs of the Messiah; and he will live long and merit [to live in] the days of the Messiah and to the life of the World to Come.
>
> תניא אמר רבי אליעזר, כל האומר שירה זו בעולם הזה, זוכה ואומרו לעולם הבא, שנאמר אז ישיר משה, שר לא נאמר אלא ישיר אותו לעתיד לבא
>
> We learned in a *baraisa*, Rabbi Eliezer said: Whoever recites this song in This World will merit to recite it in the World to Come, as it is said, "Then Moses will sing" (*Exodus* 15:1). It does not say he *sang*, rather he *will sing* it, in the Time to Come.
>
> תניא רבי אליעזר הגדול אומר, כל העוסק בפרק שירה זה בכל יום, מעיד אני עליו שהוא בן עולם הבא, ונצול מפגע רע, ומיצר הרע, ומדין קשה, ומשטן, ומכל מיני משחית ומזיקין. גמור בכל לבבך ובכל נפשך לדעת דרכי ולשמור דלתות היכלי ותורתי  ולשמור מצותי וחקי. נצור תורתי בלבבך ונגד עיניך תהיה יראתי. שמור פיך ולשונך מכל חטא ואשמה, ואני אהיה עמך בכל מקום שתלך, ואלמדך שכל ובינה מכל דבר. והוי יודע שכל מה שברא הקדוש ברוך הוא לא בראו כי אם לכבודו, שנאמר כל הנקרא בשמי ולכבודי בראתיו יצרתיו אף עשיתיו
>
> We learned in a *baraisa*, Rabbi Eliezer the Great said: Whoever is engrossed in this *Perek Shirah* every day, I testify about him that he is destined for the World to Come, that he will be rescued from an evil occurrence, from the Evil Inclination, from a harsh judgement, from Satan, and from every manner of destruction and those that cause harm. [God says to him,] "Study with all your heart and all your soul to know My ways, to safeguard the doors of My Sanctuary and My Torah, and to observe My commandments and decrees. Guard My Torah in your heart and let fear of Me be opposite your eyes. Safeguard your mouth and tongue from all sin and guilt – then I will be with you wherever you go, and I will teach you discernment and understanding from every subject." You should know that whatever the Holy One, blessed is He, created, He created it only for His glory, as it says, "Everyone who is called by My Name and whom I have created for My glory, whom I have fashioned, even perfected" (*Isaiah* 43:7).
>
> אמרו חז״ל על דוד מלך ישראל, בשעה שסים ספר תהילים זחה דעתו עליו ואמר לפני הקדוש ברוך הוא, יש בריה שבראת בעולמך שאומרת שירות ותשבחות יותר ממני. באותה שעה נזדמנה לו צפרדע אחת, ואמרה לו, דוד אל תזוח דעתך עליך, שאני אומרת שירות ותשבחות יותר ממך. ולא עוד אלא כל שירה שאני אומרת ממשלת עליה שלשת אלפים משלים, שנאמר וידבר שלשת אלפים משל ויהי שירו חמשה ואלף. ולא עוד אלא שאני עוסקת במצוה גדולה, וזו היא המצוה שאני עוסקת בה, יש בשפת הים מין אחד שאין פרנסתו כי אם אלא מן המים, ובשעה שהוא רעב נוטלני ואוכלני. זו היא המצוה. לקים מה שנאמר אם רעב שונאך האכילהו לחם, ואם צמא השקהו מים, כי גחלים אתה חותה על ראשו, וה׳ ישלם לך. אל תקרי ישלם לך אלא ישלימנו לך.
>
> Our Sages of blessed memory said about David, King of Israel: When he completed the Book of *Psalms*, he felt proud and he said before the Holy One, blessed is He, "Have You created any creature in Your world that recites songs and praises more than I?" That moment, a single frog encountered him and said to him, "David, do not feel pride, for I recite songs and praises more than you. Not only that, but three thousand parables can be derived from every song that I recite, as it says, '[Solomon] spoke three thousand proverbs, and his songs were one thousand and five' (*I Kings* 5:12). What is more, I am involved in a great mitzvah, and this is the mitzvah with which I am engaged: At the sea shore, there is a species whose sustenance is only from the water, and when it is hungry, it takes me and eats me." This is the mitzvah – to fulfill what is said, "If your foe is hungry, feed him bread, and if he is thirsty, give him water to drink, for you will be scooping coals [to heap] on his head, and Hashem will reward you" (*Proverbs* 25:21-22). Do not read it, "He will reward you," but "He shall cause him to make peace with you."
>
> רבי ישעיה תלמידו של רבי חנינא בן דוסא התענה חמש ושמונים תעניות, אמר כלבים שכתוב בהם והכלבים עזי נפש לא ידעו שבעה יזכו לומר שירה. וענה לו מלאך מן השמים, ואמר לו ישעיה עד מתי אתה מתענ על זה הדבר, שבועה היא מלפני המקום ברוך הוא מיום שגלה סודו לחבקוק הנביא לא גלה דבר זה לשום בריה בעולם, אלא בשביל שתלמידו של אדם גדול אתה, שלחוני מן השמים לזדקק אליך, ואמרו כלבים כתיב בנם ולכל בני ישראל לא יחרץ כלב לשונו, ולא עוד אלא שזכו לעבד עורות מצואתם, שכותבין בהם תפילין ומזוזות וספר תורה, על כן זכו לומר שירה. ואל תוסיף בדבר הזה עוד, כמו שכתוב שומר פיו ולשונו שומר מצרות נפשו
>
> Rabbi Yeshayah, a disciple of Rabbi Chanina ben Dosa, fasted eighty-five fasts. He said, "Dogs, of whom it is written, 'The dogs are greedy; they do not know satiation' (Isaiah 56:10) – should they merit to sing [praise of God]?" An angel answered him from heaven, and said, "Yeshayah, how long will you fast over this matter? The Omnipresent One took an oath; from the day He revealed His secret to the prophet Habakkuk, He did not reveal this matter to any creature in the world, but because you are a disciple of a great man, they have sent me from Heaven to respond to you. They said: It is written about dogs that 'But against all the Children of Israel, no dog shall whet its tongue' (*Exodus* 11:7). What is more, they merited that parchments tanned with their excrement are used to write *tefillin*, *mezuzos*, and a Torah scroll. Therefore they merit to recite song. Regarding what you asked, withdraw and do not bring this matter up again, as it is written, 'One who guards his mouth and his tongue guards his soul from troubles' (*Proverbs* 21:23)."

**Where are these quotes originally from?**

Comment: Why do you make it so long? Is it necessary to bring the whole passage? What do you mean by "originally from" - what Midrash?

Comment: @Al I think it is necessary to bring the whole passage, because otherwise people won't know what it is that I'm looking for. Yes, that's what I mean by "originally from."

Answer (score 0):

- The fourth passage regarding David HaMelech, until "What is more, I am involved in a great mitzvah": With minor changes, it can be found in [Yalkut Shimoni, Nach §889](https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach.889.2).
- The final passage regarding R' Yeshaya: With minor changes, it can be found in [Yalkut Shimoni, Torah §187](https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Torah.187.1).

Still looking for sources on the other three and a half passages; please feel free to edit with additional sources if you find any.

Comment: Note most things found in Yalkut Shimoni can be found in earlier sources which we have. Fancier versions will give you the source.